# Construction 3x3 Matrix using rows and columns-python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that uses two nested while loops to print the rows and columns of a 3x3 grid (numbered 1 to 3), excluding the cells along the diagonal (i.e., where the row and column have the same value).

I wrote the code but it only prints:
1,2 and 1,3

Here is my code:

```py
row=0
col=0
while row<3:
    row= row+1
    while col<3:
        col= col+1
        if col==row:
            pass
        else:
            print(row,col)
```

Instead, it's supposed to print 1,2 1,3 2,1 2,3 3,1 and 3,2

Comment: Set `col=0` after inner while loop. Else value of `col` for subsequent outer while loops is always 3 and hence after first iteration of outer loop its bypassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset your col variable before entering the second while loop.

Like this:

```
row=0
while row<3:
    row = row+1
    col = 0
    while col<3:
        col= col+1
        if col==row:
            pass
        else:
            print(row,col)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,4):
  print()
  for j in range(1,4):
    if i != j:
      print(i ,',', j)
```

Comment: You can remove the empty print statement if you need the output on a single line